# Why does onMonthChanged callback not work in my Flutter Calendar (NeatCleanCalendar)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, calendar

I have been working with NeatCleanCalendar and was creating a system to create events on certain weekdays like your average alarm app (For example, a 'Exercise' event that occurs on Mondays, Tuesdays, and Wednesdays). However, as it is not efficient to try and brute force the creation of all these events at once, I wanted to use the onMonthChanged callback to implement lazy loading so that the events are only created when the user navigates to the next month. However, I have been running into issues with this as the callback is not triggered when I use the navigation arrows or swipe to the next month. I was under the impression that this would trigger the calllback but it does not. I've tried looking online for solutions but to no avail. Is there an error on my part or is this something that is currently being fixed? Many thanks for your time and I hope I made sense!

```
body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0, left: 8),
            child: Text(
              "Good $greetingTimeVariable, $userName!",
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 34,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              elevation: 20,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
              color: userChosenAccent,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Calendar(
                  onMonthChanged: (value) {
                    debugPrint(value.toString());
                    if (loadedMonths.contains(value)) {
                      return;
                    } else {
                      loadedMonths.add(value);
                      for (int i = 0; i < recurringEvents.length; i++) {
                        DateTime dateCounter = value;
                        while (dateCounter.month == value.month) {
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.sunday) &&
                              everySunday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.monday) &&
                              everyMonday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.tuesday) &&
                              everyTuesday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.wednesday) &&
                              everyWednesday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.thursday) &&
                              everyThursday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.friday) &&
                              everyFriday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if ((dateCounter.weekday == DateTime.saturday) &&
                              everySaturday!) {
                            eventsList.add(
                              NeatCleanCalendarEvent(
                                recurringEvents[i].summary!,
                                startTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenStartTime!.hour,
                                  chosenStartTime!.minute,
                                ),
                                endTime: DateTime(
                                  dateCounter.year,
                                  dateCounter.month,
                                  dateCounter.day,
                                  chosenEndTime!.hour,
                                  chosenEndTime!.minute,
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }

                          dateCounter =
                              dateCounter.add(const Duration(days: 1));
                          debugPrint("Finished the while loop!");
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    debugPrint("The month has been changed to: $value");
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  hideTodayIcon: true,
                  displayMonthTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                  eventTileHeight: 70,
                  onEventLongPressed: (value) {
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text("Delete this note?"),
                        content: TextButton(
                          child: const Text("Delete"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            for (int i = 0; i < notelist.length; i++) {
                              if (((notelist[i].corrSummary == value.summary) &&
                                  (notelist[i].date == value.startTime))) {
                                onNoteDeleted(i);
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                setState(() {});
                              }
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  onEventSelected: (value) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < notelist.length; i++) {
                      debugPrint("Trying to edit the note!");
                      if (((notelist[i].corrSummary == value.summary) &&
                          (notelist[i].date == value.startTime))) {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(
                              toBeEditedNote: notelist[i],
                              userChosenAccent: userChosenAccent,
                              corrSummary: value.summary,
                              date: value.startTime,
                              onNoteEdited: (editedNote) =>
                                  onNoteEdited(i, editedNote),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        debugPrint("Trying to add new note!");
                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => NewNoteScreen(
                              onNewNoteCreated: onNewNoteCreated,
                              userChosenAccent: userChosenAccent,
                              date: value.startTime,
                              corrSummary: value.summary,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }

                    if (notelist.isEmpty) {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => NewNoteScreen(
                            onNewNoteCreated: onNewNoteCreated,
                            userChosenAccent: userChosenAccent,
                            date: value.startTime,
                            corrSummary: value.summary,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  onDateSelected: _onDateSelected,
                  dayOfWeekStyle: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  eventsList: eventsList,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  defaultDayColor: Colors.white,
                  selectedColor: userChosenAccent.shade900,
                  selectedTodayColor: userChosenAccent.shade900,
                  todayColor: userChosenAccent.shade900,
                  defaultOutOfMonthDayColor: Colors.white60,
                  eventColor: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onNewNoteCreated(Note note) {
    notelist.add(note);
    setState(() {});
  }

  void onNoteDeleted(int index) {
    notelist.removeAt(index);
    setState(() {});
  }

  void onNoteEdited(int index, Note note) {
    setState(() {
      notelist[index] = note;
    });
  }
}
```